How to add timeout to async websocket if no ping received from server
I am subscribed/connected to a websocket where I receive continuous market data.  I have written the code to automatically reconnect if disconnected.  It works fine for a while, maybe even for days, but eventually it stops receiving data and appears to do nothing.  The markets are still live so I am sure it is supposed to be receiving data.  The data provider says their server sends pings periodically to keep the connection alive but do not expect any pings from the client.  How do I change my code so that if it does not receive anything, it will drop the connection and restart?
My code is:
async def wsrun(uri):
        async for websocket in websockets.connect(uri):
                try:
                    (websocket processing code here)
                except Exception as error:
                        print(error)
                        continue


for this to be answeerable we need a bit more of the code you have there - at least the line which actually awaits for data to come from the websockect side, and th elooping code

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
